# Working of PDA for $\{a^m b^n c^k \mid m=n \text{ or } n=k\}$

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

I understand that the language $L = \{ a^mb^nc^k \mid m=n \text{ or } n=k \}$ is context-free because it can be represented as the union of $L_1 = \{a^mb^mc^k\}$ and $L_2 = \{a^mb^kc^k\}$, which are both context-free. But I can't figure out the working of the PDA accepting $L$.

To check whether $m=n$, first of all $m$ many $a$'s will be pushed, then on every occurrence of $b$, one $a$ will be popped out, or if stack becomes empty, then remaining $b$'s will be pushed. After this, either stack will be empty, meaning $m=n$, or $m-n$ many $a$'s or $n-m$ many $b$'s will remain in the stack, meaning $m \neq n$. How can we check whether $n=k$ now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDA first guesses whether $m=n$ or $n=k$. According to the guess, it either just checks that $m=n$, or just checks that $n=k$.

What your heuristic argument suggests is that this language cannot be accepted by a *deterministic* PDA. You can likely show this by adapting the proof [here](http://www.cs.nuim.ie/%7Ejpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node38.html).

Comment: Yes, now I got it. The key here is- DPDA cannot guess which condition is true but NPDA can due to non-determinism. This question is also relevant to NPDA and non-determinism: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79617/do-npda-work-in-parallel